# How can I get the linear layout to fill the parent page in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

[image: pagecontroller]

I have created a pagecontroller application and added it on my page in its own linear layout.
However, I can not get the layout width to fill the entire parent page..
This is my code:

```
pagecontrol = new LinearLayout(this.context);
pagecontrol.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
pagecontrol.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
pagecontrol.addView(btn,params);

public LinearLayout getView() {
        return pagecontrol;
    }
```

I have attached the screenshot of the page. Could anyone please advise?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Comment: I tried this but, the image resources I use get stretched out :(

Comment: I did try this before but my background image resource gets stretched out

Comment: Did you try to use `android:layout_margin｀？

Comment: Whose `layout width` do you want to fill the entire parent page? The `pagecontrol` (the long black strip in bottom?) seems to have filled the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

You must use these properties.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: I tried this but, the image resources I use get stretched out :(

Comment: This is normal. Then you must change image properties.

Comment: I did try this before but my background image resource gets stretched out

Comment: See thats the thing, I am using radio buttons whose background I have set to these image resources..

Answer (score 0):

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

replace WRAP_CONTENT with FILL_PARENT it will work

Comment: I tried this but, the image resources I use get stretched out :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check the height and width of layout if you take the outer layout of your linear layout.

Change it:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```